# Updating restaurant locations when map position moves

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

This code successfully shows nearby restaurants using Google Places API based on my current location. When I manually move the map position on my phone, though, new restaurant markers do not show in the new location of the map. Below is my code. I also have commented out something I was trying to do to update the markers to the new camera position. I used onCameraMove in the Google Maps. Any help with updating new restaurant markers based on the new camera position is greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:family_farms_forever/utilities/secrets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/marker_updates.dart';

        void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

final places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: Secrets.iosApiKey);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Market Map",
      home: Scaffold(
          // We'll change the AppBar title later
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("My Location")),
          body: const MyMarketMap()),
    );
  }
}

class MyMarketMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyMarketMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyMarketMapState();
  }
}

class _MyMarketMapState extends State<MyMarketMap> {
  late Future<Position> _currentLocation;
  late final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentLocation = Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  Future<void> _retrieveNearbyRestaurants(LatLng userLocation) async {
    PlacesSearchResponse response = await places.searchNearbyWithRadius(
        Location(lat: userLocation.latitude, lng: userLocation.longitude),
        10000,
        type: "restaurant");

    Set<Marker> restaurantMarkers = response.results
        .map((result) => Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(result.name),
            // Use an icon with different colors to differentiate between current location
            // and the restaurants
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                BitmapDescriptor.hueAzure),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: result.name,
                snippet:
                    "Ratings: ${result.rating?.toString() ?? "Not Rated"}"),
            position: LatLng(
                result.geometry!.location.lat, result.geometry!.location.lng)))
        .toSet();

    setState(() {
      _markers.addAll(restaurantMarkers);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _currentLocation,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // The user location returned from the snapshot
              Position snapshotData = snapshot.data;
              LatLng userLocation =
                  LatLng(snapshotData.latitude, snapshotData.longitude);

              if (_markers.isEmpty) {
                _retrieveNearbyRestaurants(userLocation);
              }

//               void upDateMarkers() {
//                 Set<Marker> updatedMarkers =
//                     {}; //new markers with updated position go here

//                 updatedMarkers = {};

//                 /// Then call the SetState function.
//                 /// I called the MarkersUpdate class inside the setState function.
//                 /// You can do it your way but remember to call the setState function so that the updated markers reflect on your Flutter app.
//                 /// Ps: I did not try the second way where the MarkerUpdate is called outside the setState buttechnically it should work.
//                 setState(() {
//                   MarkerUpdates.from(Set<Marker>.from(_markers),
//                       Set<Marker>.from(updatedMarkers));
//                   _markers = updatedMarkers;
//                   _markers.addAll(updatedMarkers);

//                   //swap of markers so that on next marker update the previous marker would be the one which you updated now.
// // And even on the next app startup, it takes the updated markers to show on the map.
//                 });
//               }

              return GoogleMap(
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                //onCameraMove: (position) => upDateMarkers(),
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: userLocation,
                  zoom: 12,
                ),
                markers: _markers
                  ..add(Marker(
                      markerId: const MarkerId("User Location"),
                      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: "User Location"),
                      position: userLocation)),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(child: Text("Failed to get user location."));
            }
          }

          // While the connection is not in the done state yet
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Stream for getting updates :

```
StreamBuilder<Position>(
      stream: Geolocator.getPositionStream(
        locationSettings: LocationSettings()
      ),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
... Do your Rest Coding Here...
```

You can control the behavior of the stream by specifying an instance of the [LocationSettings] class for the [locationSettings] parameter. Standard settings are:
LocationSettings.accuracy: allows controlling the precision of the position updates by supplying (defaults to "best");
LocationSettings.distanceFilter: allows controlling the minimum distance the device needs to move before the update is emitted (default value is 0 which indicates no filter is used);
LocationSettings.timeLimit: allows for setting a timeout interval. If between fetching locations the timeout interval is exceeded a [TimeoutException] will be thrown. By default no time limit is configured.

Comment: I replaced my FutureBuilder with StreamBuilder from your code but all I get is the circle progress indicator (indicating the connection is not in the done state). No GoogleMap even shows on the screen, just a blank screen with the progress indicator. Is there any other part of the code I need to change?

Comment: Do you have any further updates on your answer?